# Set active clip in Motion Tracking workspace via Python

Tags: python, tracking

Is it possible to set the active clip in the Motion Tracking workspace?

```
clip = bpy.data.movieclips.load(filepath)
#somehow set the clip as the active
```

- By active I mean that it displays in the viewer so I don't have to select it in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Set active clip in all Movie Clip Editor in current workspace

```
import bpy

clip = ...

spaces = []
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == "CLIP_EDITOR":
                if space.view == "CLIP":
                    spaces.append(space)


for space in spaces:
    space.clip = clip
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciated!